# how to refresh page when hitting api endpoint (nuxt.js)

Tags: node.js, database, rest, api, nuxt.js

I'm making an app that displays a list of orders. The problem is when I submit a new order by hitting an endpoint with a post request with the data for a new order, the page or the components need to refresh automatically to display this new order. I don't know how this is achieved with nuxt. The client-side HTML rendering needs to be actively reacting to events happening on the server-side.

Answer (score 0):

So, you don't actually need to refresh the page to do this, you can use axios to POST an order and update your page with that particular order

```
export default {
    data(){
    return {
      newOrder: null
    }
  },
  methods:{
      newOrder(){
         const newOrder = await this.$axios.post(...)
         this.newOrder = newOrder
      },
  }
}
```